# XSLT 2.0 check if Element is missing by predefined list

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML File:

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="1" Value="test1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2" Value="test2"></Item>
</Items>
```

What I want to transform with a predefined list:

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="1">
        <Value OldValue="test1" NewValue="TEST1" ></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="2">
        <Value OldValue="test2" NewValue="TEST2" ></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="3">
        <Value OldValue="" NewValue="TEST3" ></Value>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

So, the value should be changed from the OldValue to the NewValue. If the Item is defined in this list and is not available in the input XML file (like Item Name="3") in this example, the Value should be set to EMPTY:

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="1" Value="TEST1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2" Value="TEST2"></Item>
    <Item Name="3" Value="EMPTY"></Item>
</Items>
```

What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3"
                xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3">


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" name="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="Items">
        <Item Name="1">
            <Value OldValue="test1" NewValue="TEST1" ></Value>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="2">
            <Value OldValue="test2" NewValue="TEST2" ></Value>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="3">
            <Value OldValue="test3" NewValue="TEST3" ></Value>
        </Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                <xsl:choose>                    
                    <xsl:when >
                        <!-- check if Item is defined in Items and missing here -->
                    </xsl:when>                   
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Items/Item[@Name=current()/@Name]/Value[@OldValue = current()/@Value]/@NewValue"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!= 'Value']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'm missing is an idea how to detect if an item is missing or not in the when clause. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this? Maybe with a function?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something: why do you need the OldValues? Is it not enough to compare the Item Names?

Comment: Yes would also be possible of course, it's just to check if the old value is correct as well, just in case I have an input file with a different value than in the $Items, it should not be changed to the NewValue because this would be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="Item" use="@Name" />
<xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />

<xsl:variable name="Items">
    <Item Name="1">
        <Value OldValue="test1" NewValue="TEST1" ></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="2">
        <Value OldValue="test2" NewValue="TEST2" ></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="3">
        <Value OldValue="test3" NewValue="TEST3" ></Value>
    </Item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Items/Item">
            <Item Name="{@Name}" Value="{Value/@NewValue}">
                <xsl:if test="not(key('item', @Name, $xml))">
                    <xsl:attribute name="Value">EMPTY</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </Item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Item Name="1" Value="TEST1"/>
   <Item Name="2" Value="TEST2"/>
   <Item Name="3" Value="EMPTY"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Yes this would work but I would rather go the other way around. To copy the Items and only change the OldValue to the NewValue when the OldValue is equal and create an attribute node if it's missing. I don't want to override data by accident. For example if there is an Item name="1" with an OldValue != "test1" I don't want to change this value to TEST1 because it would be wrong. I'm working with awkward data, this is just an example.

Comment: @user3891252 I'm afraid I don't follow your explanation. IIUC, you cannot go by the items in the source XML, because that way no item is ever "missing". Perhaps you should expand on your question, with more complex example/s.

Comment: Yes you are right this would not be possible. So maybe I can check if an Item is missing before I go through them and save the missing Items to a variable?

Comment: @user3891252 Yes, that would be possible - or you could add a template matching only the "missing" items in the variable. But the result would be different from what you showed us at first, would it not? `"test1"` instead of `"TEST1"`, etc.

Comment: How can I compare 2 element nodes in order to check if there are missing elements? If I save this to a variable I could check if the current Item is in the list of missing Items and then chenge it's value attribute to empty.

Comment: In order to make things more clear, the source XML represents a formular what is filled out and if the Item is missing, it means that the field was not filled out and therefore I want to set the value attribute to EMPTY.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense: the current item will **never** be in the list of missing items. -- I suggest again you edit your question and add all these explanations there.